# Which Desert Father is known to have undone his work at the end of the day?

Tags: church-fathers, reference-request

I once heard a story of a desert father who would do some work, maybe construction of some type, and then proceed to undo it all at the end of the day, repeating the next day in order to highlight the vanity of human works. Where is the source for this story and which individual was this?

Comment: I hope that didn't include planting seeds in the ground then digging them all out the next day. Or digging a well, only to fill it all in. Hopefully, someone can quote a reliable source that spells it all out, exactly.

Comment: I suggest this question should be asked on [SE-Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: I remember reading this story, but can not place it now.